# How to set hyperlinks on textview on Telegram bot in Java?

Tags: java, telegram, telegram-bot

So am new in Telegram bot and am very familiar in java.Basically am a fan of gang mafia telegram bot.On the below  screenshot i would like to know how to develop something like that [image]

On my perspective i get you have to give or make those text hyperlink first and then give or set some listeners.How Does one develop something like that?

this is my code

```
public class Pizza {
private static final Logger LOG = Logger.getLogger(Pizza.class.getName());

    public static void main(String... args) throws Exception {
        TelegramBotsApi telegramBotsApi = new TelegramBotsApi();
        telegramBotsApi.registerBot(new TelegramLongPollingBot() {


            @Override
            public void onUpdateReceived(Update update) {
                Message message = update.getMessage();
                Long chatId = message.getChatId();
                String input = message.getText();
                if ("/recommend".equals(input)) {
                    SendMessage request = new SendMessage();
                    request.setChatId(chatId.toString());
                    request.setText("Peperoni");
                    try {
                        sendMessage(request);
                    } catch (TelegramApiException e) {
                        LOG.log(Level.SEVERE, "Could not send message", e);
                    }
   @Override
            public String getBotUsername() {
                return "USERNAME_BOT";
            }

            @Override
            public String getBotToken() {
                return "BOT_TOKEN";
            }


        });
    }

}
```

Please need help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you don't need to add any link info to those words starting with `/`. In a conversation with bots, every word starting with `/` is consider a bot command and therefore, marked as clickable by the app. But you need, indeed, to make code to manage those commands in your bot.